# error in command show slave status | find "Last_SQL_Error" in windows

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

i try to execute the command show slave status | find "Last_SQL_Error" in windows in windows 
but it returns to me an error. Can someone correct  it to me.
best regards

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? And which error do you get?

Comment: im talking about mysql the error is : you have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` at the dos prompt and then extract the `Last_SQL_Error` values. If that's correct then you should probably use `findstr`, not `find`. Something like this:

```
mysql -e "show slave status\G" | findstr "Last_SQL_Error"
```

Comment: exactly its my aim but for this command: mysql -e "show slave status\G" | findstr "Last_SQL_Error" if i want to log in mysql (mysql -u root -p) do i have to combine these two command or execute one by one

Comment: i add mysql -u root -p -e "show slave status\G" | findstr "Last_SQL_Error". exactly what im loking for. Thank You so much for the help.